# Save two model (One contains foreign key) data from a single template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm pretty new to django and working on a blog based project where user can add ratings to specific type of review post.For example giving stars are enabled for restaurant but not for tech stores.

I have created two different form for "review" and "star" model. I want to rate the restaurant using the model named "star" and do it in same template.But I'm having difficulties to do that.

Im getting this error.
"**The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: reviews_star.post_id_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:**"

How do I get the review id that I just save with "review_form.save()".

my review model kinda looks like this (Removed other attributes which aren't related to this problem):

```
class Review(models.Model):
      review_title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Title', max_length=100)
      review_body = models.TextField()
      author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
      restaurant_or_techstore = models.CharField(verbose_name='Foods or Travel',max_length=20)
      slug = models.SlugField(null=False,unique=True,max_length = 300)
```

My rating model looks like this:

```
class Star(models.Model):
      post_id = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
      food = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Food',null=False)  
      service = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Food',null=False)
      cleanliness = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Food',null=False)
```

and my view :

```
def CreateReview(request):
ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Image,form=ImageForm,extra=5)


if request.method == 'POST':
    reviewForm = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES,queryset=Image.objects.none())
    starsForm = StarsrForm(request.POST)

    if reviewForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and starsForm.is_valid():
        review_form = reviewForm.save(commit=False)
        review_form.author = request.user
        review_form.post_or_discussion = 1
        review_form.food_or_travel = 'Foods'
        review_form.save()
        reviewForm.save_m2m()

        starsForm.save()

        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            if form:
                image = form['image']
                photo = Image(review=review_form,image=image)
                photo.save()
        messages.success(request,'Image Uploaded Successfully')
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        print(reviewForm.errors, formset.errors)
else:
    reviewForm = ReviewForm()
    starsForm = StarsrForm()
    formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Image.objects.none())
return render(request,'reviews/review_form.html',{'reviewForm':reviewForm,'formset':formset,'starsForm':starsForm})
```

Answer (score 0):

best try when you use ForeighKey is to use related_name attr for this field

```
class Star(models.Model):
      post = models.ForeignKey(Review, related_name='post_review', on_delete = models.CASCADE )
```

after it you can refer to star from review by **some_object_review.post_review.some_field_star**

For you error above try **reviews_star.post_id.id**

Comment: Can you explain it bit more ? I'm having hard time understanding it. Also it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solve The problem.All I had to do is pass the review_form instance to the star form.**

new view is:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

    reviewForm = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST,request.FILES,queryset=Image.objects.none())
    starsForm = StarsrForm(request.POST)


    if reviewForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and starsForm.is_valid():
        review_form = reviewForm.save(commit=False)
        review_form.author = request.user
        review_form.post_or_discussion = 1
        review_form.food_or_travel = 'Foods'
        review_form.save()
        reviewForm.save_m2m()
        instance = review_form
        print(instance.id)
        star_form = starsForm.save(commit=False)
        star_form.post_id = instance
        star_form.save()

        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            if form:
                image = form['image']
                photo = Image(review=review_form,image=image)
                photo.save()
        messages.success(request,'Image Uploaded Successfully')
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    else:
        print(reviewForm.errors, formset.errors)
else:
    reviewForm = ReviewForm()
    starsForm = StarsrForm()
    formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Image.objects.none())
return render(request,'reviews/review_form.html',{'reviewForm':reviewForm,'formset':formset,'starsForm':starsForm})
```